# conjecture about prime numbers and distance between them

Tags: prime-numbers, summation, conjectures

is there a name for this conjecture?

**Conjecture:** given $p_n$ a prime number sequence where $p_1=2,p_2=3,\cdots$, then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, holds that $\displaystyle p_{n+2+k}-p_{n+1}\le\sum_{i=0}^{k}p_{n+i}$

Comment: Do you actually mean the sequence with the $n$'th prime as the $n$'th term? It clearly fails for an arbitrary sequence of primes.

Comment: yes, the sequence where the n'th term as the n'th prime.

Comment: While the phrase "prime gap" is used to describe the difference between two consecutive primes, this statement concerns the difference of two primes that are $k+1$ terms apart in the sequence of primes.  As a matter of nomenclature it's probably just as well to refer to it as a conjecture about prime differences (though of course it can be viewed as a consecutive sum of $k$ prime gaps, or expressed as an average of consecutive prime gaps).

Comment: The conjecture is equivalent to $p_n+p_{n+1}\geqslant p_{n+2}$ for all $n$. Not sure if this follows somewhat immediately from Bertrand's postulate or has another name.